# 'Permission denied' problem with 'scp' while building blockchain

Tags: server, scp

Recently I built blockchain system about Hyperledger.
I met error 'Permission denied' while broadcasting MSPservice to other node.
Please refer below.

[image]

Comment: For future posts here, please copy/paste terminal output instead of including images.

Comment: Is that a Korean character in the output, and is that intended?

Comment: When I ask question, I will paste the terminal! sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to `scp` a file from one machine (or virtual machine) to another.  When you issue the `scp` command, you authenticate to the remote system using the user `ssgyee`, as this is the user you specify in the command.  This does not match the user `fabric`, which is likely the owner of the `/home/fabric` directory.

As a very quick test, you could try `scp`'ing the file to the remote `/tmp` directory, or a directory in `/home/ssgyee`.  You should have write permission to these directories, and `scp` should work in this test case.

On the remote system, take a look at the permissions of the target or destination directory:

```bsh
ls -lsha /home/
```

I suspect that this will show `fabric:fabric` owning `/home/fabric`, and this is a sane and secure default.  Each user has a directory within `/home` that they control.  If you want the to be able to write to the `/home/fabric` directory, you will need to authenticate as `fabric`, or add `ssgyee` to the `fabric` group using `groupadd`, or by editing `/etc/group`.  In addition to being in the group, the `/home/fabric` (or any other directory within) will need group read, write and execute permissions.

Files belong to users and groups.  Files have specific permissions, per user, group, and then 'all others'.  Linux users and groups, as well as file [ownership and permissions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html) are essential to understand when dealing with Linux.

> Remember that file permissions are a security feature. Whenever you allow anyone else to read, write to, and execute files, you are increasing the risk of files being tampered with, altered, or deleted. As a rule, you should only grant read and write permissions to those who truly need them.

Comment: very very apprecuate about your solution. I refered your description and solution. I typed 'ls -lsha /home/ to ssgyee@client, ssgyee@peer0. However, real problem is address of the directory. I checked the directory and I change the directory from '/home/fabric' to '/home/ssgyee/fabric'. Then I saw success message. By uour solution, I can know importance of permission. Thank you again :D